# How to create pseudo synchronous download in WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, asynchronous

I have a class with public DownloadAsync Method inside, that downloads Content over Webclient. I create an Object of that class and call the download Method.

My problem is: I would like to block Elements on UI (e.g. Buttons) until the download is done. I could not find any solution so far.

One Idea is: I could call a MessageBox with message like "download is done" in the Downloadcomplete Method and to call somehow an Eventhandler for MessageBox. But how?

Any idea how to solve my problem?

EDIT: I know hot to disable Elements, but because of asynchronuous download in the download method, I don't know when the download is over in order to enable back the elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an event to your data class, and when the download has finished then trigger the event handler.

then in your page do something like this in your initialiser

```
  BusyMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
  this.DataContext = MYDownloaderClass.downloadedData;
  MyDownloaderClass.hasFinished += new EventHandler(hasFinished);

}

void hasFinished(object sender, EventArgs e){
  BusyMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
}
```

Comment: thanky you! for people who search how to create an event hanlder: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842339/how-to-trigger-event-when-a-variables-value-is-changed]

Answer (score 0):

You should just disable all the elements - set IsEnabled to false on buttons etc. If you want a quick and dirty solution - you can overlay the screen with a Rectangle, Border, Grid or Popup.

Answer (score 0):

Try a busy indicator with an overlay.
http://www.minddriven.de/index.php/technology/dot-net/windows-phone/wp7-xaml-viewmodel-busy-indicator

Comment: I have edited now my question, because my problem is: when should I activate back the controls? WebClient Calls DownloadAsyncCompleted Method, but I use an instance of the class, calling the public download Method, so there is no callback to the UI :\

Comment: Joseph's solution will work.  If you're using mvvm, this http://baud.cz/blog/coproject-ria-caliburnmicro-demo-part-10 is a nice way to do busy.  Separately, the with the async ctp you can make some of the callback business go away.