# How can I raise an event in an object

Tags: c#, events

In C#, if I have an event in a class, how can I raise this event?

I have a class called `test`, with the following event:

```
public event PropertyValueChangedEventHandler PropertyValueChanged
```

I have a `PropertyGrid` object that is in a `CollectionEditor`, and I want to raise the `PropertyValueChanged` event in the `test` object when the `CollectionEditor.PropertyGrid` value is changed.

I am not sure of the correct code to do this, this is what I have so far with a `test` object called `obj`:

```
propertyGridObject.PropertyValueChanged += customWebpageHtmlNode.PropertyValueChanged;
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Just do it in the setter of `PropertyGrid`.

Comment: Can you please explain.

Comment: I mean this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842339/how-to-trigger-event-when-a-variables-value-is-changed

Comment: `INotifyProperty` is what you are looking for ??

Comment: You can't raise an event from anywhere except in the class that defines the event.

Comment: Can you please clarify if you are asking "how to raise an event defined in `test` from **within** `test`" or do you mean "how to raise an event defined in `test` from another object/class"?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(PropertyValueChanged != null)
       PropertyValueChanged(with parameters defined on the signature of PropertyValueChangedEventHandler)
```