# How a function can be automatically called upon a variable change?

Tags: c#, class, function-call

I have a class consisting of variable members and a function member. The variable member occasionally changes. I want the function to be called automatically upon the variable changes. In other words, how can I tie the variables inside a class?

```
class line
{
   double x, y; // The poition of the lind end. The line starts at the origin (0,0)
   double l; // The length of the line
   void length()
   {
      l = Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y);
   }
}
```

In example above, I need the length to be updated when x and y change.

Comment: How would you envision this mechanism working?  This isn't magic...something has to be checking the values of x and y and calling your method once they change...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger event when a variable's value is changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842339/how-to-trigger-event-when-a-variables-value-is-changed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your variables into properties, then put your functions in the set accesors.

```
class line
{
    double _x, _y;

    double x
    {
        get { return _x; }
        set
        {
            _x = value;
            length();
        }
    }

    double y
    {
        get { return _y; }
        set
        {
            _y = value;
            length();
        }
    }

    double l; // The length of the line

    void length()
    {
        l = Math.Sqrt(_x * _x + _y * _y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ben. Now I have another problem. I wrapped x and y over a class. Therefore x and y are updated without setting. Since I never set the variables, length() never be called.

Comment: You may want to look at events and event handlers

Answer (score 2):

If you define properties, on your class, you can make `X` and `Y` [autoprops](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx), then make a read-only property `L` that is calculated from these values:

```
public class Line //class names should be Capitalized
{
   public double X{ get; set; } //prop names should be Capitalized
   public double Y{ get; set; }
   public double L{
    get{
      return Math.Sqrt(X * X + Y * Y);
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can you properties

```
int x
int X {
   get { return x; }
   set { x = value; YouMethod();}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can achieve pretty similar behavior using calculated property like

   ```
   double Length
   {
       get { return Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y); }
   }
   ```

   The only caveat is that calculation is performed upon each call to `Length` even if `x` and `y` haven't changed.
2. You can encapsulate you `x` and `y` fields into properties and call `length` function from setter like

   ```
   double X
   {
       get { return x; }
       set 
       {
           x = value;
           length();
       }
   }

   double Y
   {
       get { return y; }
       set 
       {
           y = value;
           length();
       }
   }
   ```

   and then change `x` and `y` ONLY via `X` and `Y` properties.

Answer (score 0):

As BenJ noted, you can use properties.

Instead of declaring x and y as simple fields inside the class. You can declare them as properties the following way :

```
private double x;
public double X
get
    {
        return this.x;
    }

    set
    {
        this.x = value;

        this.length()
        //Above line will call your desired method
    }
```